# Nmbd limiting mdns interfaces

Tags: samba

Is there a way to limit which interfaces `nmbd` uses for announcing the service? I've got multiple bridges which really shouldn't be getting the `_smb.tcp` entries, but by default they do.

I've got:

```
  interfaces = lo eno1
  bind interfaces only = yes
```

in `smbd.conf` already, but that does not affect `nmbd`.

The only option that looks related is `remote announce` - but that's for broadcasting, not name registration. How can I limit the interfaces for `nmbd`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like limiting the interfaces is just not implemented. Looking at https://github.com/samba-team/samba/blob/e742661bd2507d39dfa47e40531dc1dca636cbbe/source3/smbd/avahi_register.c#L143

It seems that it's `smbd` that does the registration and it selects `AVAHI_IF_UNSPEC` which results in all interfaces getting the entry.